# .Net Core Authentication Expire Redirect Path different than Login Path

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, cookies

Im using .NetCore 2.1, and am using the code below to create authentication cookie for the user. I would like the user to be thrown to a different URL upon Expiration than their login. Essentially to a page that says your session has expired, click to continue. Is there an easy way to go about this?

I understand that LogoutPath is different than LoginPath, but Im not understanding what it does fully.

```
        services.AddAuthentication(SecurityPermissionHelper.GetAuthenticationSchemeName(AuthDataSettings.ApplicationName))           .AddCookie(SecurityPermissionHelper.GetAuthenticationSchemeName(AuthDataSettings.ApplicationName), options =>
        {
            options.ReturnUrlParameter = "/Home/Logout";
            options.LoginPath = "/Home/Welcome/";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            options.LogoutPath = "/Home/Logout/"; //Not what you think it does
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this reliably. You can only redirect in response to a request and as session_end runs independently of a browser request you can't use it to redirect the client. Basically you can't force the browser to navigate to a page via a server-event, only from a page request. So you have a few options I will say below, but they aren't very good.

One option is to use a javascript timer which is unreliable, especially if the user has multiple browser tabs open at once with one keeping the session going and the other idle. Throw into this issues where the session expires for reasons other than a timeout, and you might as well just not bother trying to do this way, unless you don't only multiple tabs opened at a given time telegram and other PWAs. You can tell when a session is a new session and take them to a page to tell them their old session expired but that's about the best you can do.

Other option is to create a SessionAttribute and stick it over ALL of your authorized methods, this too is not fluid. I tested this is MVC, so it should carry over to .Net Core, but yeah. Basically what you are wanting to do really doesn't make a whole lot of session using the inbuilt session tools from Microsoft.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class CheckSessionTimeOutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var context = filterContext.HttpContext;
        if (context.Session != null)
        {
            if (context.Session.IsNewSession)
            {
                string sessionCookie = context.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                if ((sessionCookie != null) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET&#95;SessionId") >= 0))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                    string redirectTo = "~/Home/Login";
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.RawUrl))
                    {
                        redirectTo = string.Format("~/Home/Login?ReturnUrl={0}",HttpUtility.UrlEncode(context.Request.RawUrl));
                    }
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(redirectTo , true);
                }
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Add to a single contoller

```
[CheckSessionTimeOut]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ViewResult Index()
{
    //Code goes here
}
```

or add to root of controller

```
[CheckSessionTimeOut]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
     return Index();
  }
}
```

Please note none of these are really great solutions. If you truly want to have control then you will most likely need to write your own custom session code, or override the existing one with your own timestamps and what not.

Comment: You could also add some code to your login page that looks for a stale cookie that went stale within the 1 hour time limit you have set, if it meets your criteria perform a 301 redirect to whatever page you are wanting to send them too, again this isn't the most fluid, but could achieve what you are wanting to some degree